# Stuck in solving an Ordinary differential equation, help needed in the solving process.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving the 9th edition of kreyszig Advanced Engineering Mathematics and got stuck on the following ordinary differential equation
$$dy/dx = y/x + (2x^3 / y)\cos(x^2)$$

Although, the final answer of the ODE is one of the following $$y = -x\sqrt{C - 2\sin(x^2)}$$ or $$y = x\sqrt{C - 2\sin(x^2)}$$
Can anybody help in the procedure. Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: according to the solution, a change of variable $u = y/x$ should work.

Comment: Thanks [@yimin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30330/yimin), it worked, I was initially putting $t = x^2$ and then after that I was putting $y/t = u$ from which at last I was getting stuck.

Comment: This can be solved either as bernoulli or exact or homogeneous or by Lie symmetry. Found solution on the internet [here](https://12000.org/tmp/solved_problems/dec_10_2023.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for insight @Nasser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your ODE as $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac1xy=y^{-1}2x^3\cos(x^2)$$Let $v=y^2$, then we get $$\frac{dv}{dx}-\frac2xv=4x^3\cos(x^2)$$Then we have $$v=x^2\int4x\cos(x^2)dx=2x^2(\sin(x^2)+C)$$Let $v=y^2$, then $$y=\pm x\sqrt{2\sin(x^2)+C}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate how you get to 3rd step from 2nd step.

Comment: The integrating factor is $e^{-\int\frac2x dx}=\frac1{x^2}$. Then substitute that in the formula $\frac1{I(x)}\int I(x)Q(x)dx$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, nice method.